# Cant get Query by method find() Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Faced the following problem when I am trying to instantiate a Query using the find method. As a result, I get a query variable containing an object instead of Query and Query's methods are not available to me.

Controller code:

```js
const hModel = require("../models/hModel");
const asyncHandler = require("../middleware/async");
exports.getAll = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let query = await hModel.find({ booked: "false" });
  query = query.select("location"); // TypeError: query.select is not a function
  console.log(query instanceof Query); // false
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: query });
});
```

`asyncHandler`:

```js
const asyncHandler = (fn) => (req, res, next) =>
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);

module.exports = asyncHandler;
```

How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: Since you `await` the response from `.find({ booked: false })`, you already have the "result" instead of "query" in `query` object. Hence, you will not find the `select` method on the result (`query`).

You should wait for the entire query to resolve if that's the intention:
`const data = await hModel.find({ booked: false}).select('location')`

Comment: Thanks,  you are right! Helps me a lot. Also can separate this methods now and await the result. Like  query = hModel.find(...);     query = query.select(...);   query = query.sort(...);   const result = await query;

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please mark it as resolved if my suggestion made you aware of the issue with your code and solved your problem.

Comment: Also, why are you passing `query` in the response body via `res.json()`?

Comment: Are there some advantages to using res.send()? I have no particular reason why I use res.json () instead -) will accept any advice

Comment: Hey, I think you got me wrong. Using res.json is absolutely right in your case as you are sending a JSON server response. My question was - why are you sending the `query` object in the response?

People usually make DB calls as you did (in the route handler) and return the resolved data from DB in the response like this `res.json({ data: resolvedData });`

I was just curious how you were using the `query` object in the JSON response at the other end (like Frontend which is consuming this API) 

Comment: I am also returning data from the database, but with additional parameters which we can extract from the request  like /api/books/?sort=name&limit=100  we can make a response more flexible. For example query.sort(req.query.sort) and query.limit(req.query.limit). I hope I got you, if not, then dont be offended, perhaps my English or programming level  not allow me to understand your question correctly  -(

Comment: Got your point 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Posting this after discussion)

The problem was:

Since you `await` the response from `.find({ booked: false })`, you already have the "result" instead of "query" in `query` object. Hence, you will not find the select method on the result (query).

You should wait for the entire query to resolve if that's the intention: `const data = await hModel.find({ booked: false}).select('location')`

```js
const hModel = require("../models/hModel");
const asyncHandler = require("../middleware/async");

exports.getAll = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const resolvedData = await hModel.find({'booked': 'false'})
                        .select('location');
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: resolvedData });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const hModel = require("../models/hModel");
const asyncHandler = require("../middleware/async");
exports.getAll = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let query = await hModel.findOne({'booked': 'false'});
    console.log("Query Res", query); //make sure you have the right response from db.
    query = query.location;
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: query });
});
```

Comment: thanks but this doesnt really solve my main problem - lack of access to Query's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const hModel = require("../models/hModel");
const asyncHandler = require("../middleware/async");

exports.getAll = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let query = await hModel.find({'booked': 'false'}, 'location');
    res.status(200).json({success: true,data: query});
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: It works if i chain methods like find(...).select(...).sort(...).limit(...), but i wanna separate them to put some logic